# How to design content share model for social network in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

This is not program bug fix problem. it looks silly, Since i don't have much experience in designing website. I want to make sure my design pattern is right before i began to write code.

I want to design a social network like google+ or facebook(only accomplish basic function like sharing content), Like google+, users can share different types of content like texts, photos, link and video.
like picture below:
[image]

I'm confused do i need to design different model for every type sharing content? like below codes:

```
class TextPost(models.Models):
    text=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    createDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author=models.OneToOneField(User)

class GalleryPost(models.Model):
    galleryTitle=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    createDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    author=models.OneToOneField(User)

class Images(models.Models):
    image = models.ImageField()
    galleryPost=models.ForeignKey(GalleryPost)

class LinkPost(models.Models):
    link=...
    createDate=...

class VideoPost(models.Models):
    video=...
```

Or put all types in one class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    createDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author=models.OneToOneField(User)
    galleryTitle=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    link=...
    video=...
```

if i choose first way, Is that easy to list all kinds of post by created date in one page?
Or is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both approaches are valid approaches, the first one is difficult to query against. You probably want to show a mixed feed of the latest content, so preferably easy to query the database against.

In that case you would want all models to have some base class, which defines the shared attributes (author, created_at). Then for the specific sub-classes, you add the desired extra attributes. See [Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) on docs.djangoproject.com.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

class LinkPost(Post):
    link = models.URLField()

class ImagePost(Post):
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do this work, I may choose the first design; But I will create a category Model like this
class Category(models.Models):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class VideoPost(models.Models):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ......